# Recursive query to get desired resultset

Tags: postgresql, recursive-query

I have three tables: Superobject, object_master and object_child.

SuperObject contains superobj_id and obj_id. obj_master contains all the details about the object.

Object_child has two columns: obj_id and child_id. It contains object and its child. A child can also have a subchild. So, an object can have multiple childs.

```
SuperObject Table                object_child table

    sobj1     obj1                 obj1      ch_obj1
    sobj1     obj2                 obj1      ch_obj2
    sobj1     obj3                 ch_obj1   ch_obj3
```

I want resultset in format:

```
obj1      ch_obj1
obj1      ch_obj2
obj1      ch_obj3
obj2      ------
obj2      ------
obj3      ------
```

I am using the following query:

```
with recursive objects as (
    select objectid
    from object_masster
    where objectid in (obj1, obj2, obj3)
    union
    select a.child_id
    from object_child a a join objects b on a.objectid = b.objectid
)
select * from objects
```

It is returning me all the children for the above objects but not in the desired format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick with recursive queries is that you need to store all of the data in the resultset of the seed bit and recursive bit of the union so you can have it to: A) perform the next lookup, B) display whatever you need when you select on the recursive CTE you've built.

So, for your requirements, we need to store the root node (the first objectid you are selecting from your master table), and then parent and child as we recursively select.

Also, because you want that root node to make it through to the end of all the recursive lookup, you need to keep selecting that through in your recursive bit of the union.

This will look something like:

```
WITH RECURSIVE objects AS (
    SELECT objectid AS root, CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(10)) AS parent, objectid AS child
    FROM object_master
    WHERE objectid IN (obj1, obj2, obj3)

    UNION

    SELECT b.root AS root, b.child AS parent, a.child_id AS child
    FROM object_child a 
        INNER JOIN objects b 
            ON a.objectid = b.child
)
SELECT root, child FROM objects
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Nevill... your excellent explanation for approaching recursive queries will always be a great help :)